# How to build a select value dropdown value in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select fruit <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li *ngFor="let fruit of Vegetables.Fruits">
            <a href="#">{{fruit.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

With above bootstrap component, when I select a value from the dropdown, it should show the selected value in that dropdown. Can someone help me out with this Problem ?

Comment: What about `<select ...><option ...></option><option ...></option></select>`?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve for the above code ? . Because I am using bootstrap and I want to achieve the above thing with bootstrap components :)

Comment: Just add "active" class to li element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of select box. Data is created in component.ts file then looped through in the html file.

So try this, Use my code to give you an example. Paste this in your component.ts file

```
cardTypes = ['American Express', 'Discover', 'Master Card', 'Visa'];
```

Then go to your HTML file and paste this in,

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
   label for="state_address">Cards</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
             </span>
  <select class="form-control" id="cardTypes"formControlName="cardTypes">
    <option *ngFor="let cardType of cardTypes">{{cardType}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No problem. Try and read through it so that it makes sense. You will need it a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

use PrimeNG

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

it has many elements in easy-to-use manner *with very less coding*

Comment: I will check and get back @EffinDJ